# Rails doesn't automatically load a template when in a namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Take routing like the following:

```
  namespace :auth do
    get 'login', to: 'auth#login'
  end
```

With a simple empty method in the controller:

```
def login
end
```

Without the namespace, it picks up the login template automatically with no problem. When I move it to the namespace, however, it switches to a `204 No Content` response and shows a rails warning page. I can add `render` to my controller method, but it should be automatic. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is your view in `app/views/auth` directory?

Comment: @Gerry Yes, and it responds if I manually set the render.

Comment: What's the name of your controller?

Comment: `AuthController`, defined as `Auth::AuthController` and located under `controllers/auth`

Comment: Then, is your directory `app/views/auth/auth`?

Comment: @Gerry The issue was needing another layer of `auth` directories, so go ahead and put your answer back and I'll accept it.

Comment: Great! I wasn't able to replicate the exact same error, so I wasn't completely sure that it would fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the views must be something like:

```
app/views/namespace/controller/view.html.erb
```

So, in your case both namespace and controller have the same name, so the path to the views should be:

```
app/views/auth/auth/login.html
```

Instead of:

```
app/views/auth/login.html
```